# Python - How would I use a single function to get information about the frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter, frames

## Python - Events, Frames and Tkinter

Here I have my GameApplication class which creates and runs the tkinter application. I would like to have it so that I can call the same function from every frame and using that function find out what frame was clicked. I'm only just diving into python now so excuse me if this seems simple.

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
# Import needed classes.
from tkinter import *


# Create the GameApplication class to run the GUI
class GameApplication(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.position_1 = Frame(width=100, height=100, bg="#CC0000")
        # This is the Frame I want to get information about.
        self.position_1.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
        self.position_1.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.position_2 = Frame(width=100, height=100, bg="#00CC00")
        # And this one too.
        self.position_2.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
        self.position_2.grid(column=1, row=0)

    def callback(self, event):
        print("?")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = GameApplication(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can give a meaningful name to each frame: `Frame(name='...', ...)` and then get back the frame name in `callback(...)` function by `str(event.widget)`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this . It's a small project I wrote in python . I have a function that checks the status of each call . I call that function after each function has been executed.

```
class Messengers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.box = tkMessageBox

    def successer(self):
        self.box.showinfo("ImageR Success", "Done YO! Go run a test :)")

    def failure(self):
        self.box.showerror('ImageR Failure', 'Yo you broke me!')
```

The code is here https://github.com/jaytarang92/imager . I use subprocess.check_ouput to make sure the call was done correctly.